# Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {com.example.stopcall.app/com.example.stopcall.app.activities.MainActivity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, fragment, roboguice

I try to intercept outgoing calls and open a pop up

`(Receiver --> FragmentActivity --> PopUpFragment)`

Im using roboguice for android

however my code crashes with this error:

```
01-01 10:32:41.396  13265-13265/com.example.stopcall.app E/﹕ mali: REVISION=Linux-r3p2-01rel3 BUILD_DATE=Fri Mar 21 13:52:50 KST 2014
01-01 10:32:41.931  13265-13265/com.example.stopcall.app E/ActivityThread﹕ Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {com.example.stopcall.app/com.example.stopcall.app.activities.MainActivity}
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {com.example.stopcall.app/com.example.stopcall.app.activities.MainActivity}
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3463)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3550)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:175)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1335)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

here is my code:

```
public class OutgoingCallReceiver extends RoboBroadcastReceiver {

    public static final String ABORT_PHONE_NUMBER = "0055";

    private static final String OUTGOING_CALL_ACTION = "android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL";
    private static final String INTENT_PHONE_NUMBER = "android.intent.extra.PHONE_NUMBER";

    @Override
    protected void handleReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.handleReceive(context, intent);

                Intent i = new Intent(context, PopupActivity.class);
                i.putExtra(Constants.DIALED_PHONE, phoneDal.getItem(phoneNumber));
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(i);
                setResultData(null);
            }
```

and

```
public class PopupActivity extends RoboFragmentActivity implements
        YesNoDialogFragment.YesNoDialogFragmentListener {

    @Inject PhoneDal phoneDal;
    public Phone phone;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //
        // btnEditName = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_edit);
        // txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
        //
        // btnEditName.setOnClickListener(this);
        phone = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(Constants.DIALED_PHONE);
        exportDatabase(Constants.DB_NAME);
        showYesNoDialog();
    }

    // The dialog fragment receives a reference to this Activity through the
    // Fragment.onAttach() callback, which it uses to call the following methods
    // defined by the NoticeDialogFragment.NoticeDialogListener interface
    @Override
    public void onDialogPositiveClick() {
        persistNumberIsAllowed();
        SendDialIntent();
        finish();
    }

    private void SendDialIntent() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel" + phone.phone));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: when you are starting `MainActivity` Activity?

Comment: it's the launcher activity. why?

Comment: as in log problem is occur by `MainActivity` Activity